# Hibernate OneToOne BiDirectional Optional Relationship: Works when inserted without optional object, Breaks when updated with new optional object

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, one-to-one

I have the following OneToOne relational setup between the two object, ChecklistItem and ButtonAction (shown in code snippets below). It's kind of a unique setup, I suppose. It's bi-directional, yet optional from the ChecklistItem side of things, and ButtonAction is the owner, storing the foreign key of the ChecklistItem as its primary key.

**ChecklistItem Class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHECKLIST_ITEM", schema = "CHKL_APP")
public class ChecklistItem implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CHECKLIST_ITEM_ID_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CHECKLIST_ITEM_ID_SEQ", sequenceName = "CHKL_APP.CHECKLIST_ITEM_ID_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(optional = true, mappedBy = "checklistItem", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ButtonAction button;

    //...
}
```

**ButtonAction Class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACTION_BUTTON", schema = "CHKL_APP")
public class ButtonAction implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "checklist_item_id", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generate-from-checklist-item", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "checklistItem"))
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generate-from-checklist-item")
    private Long checklistItemId;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @JsonIgnore
    private ChecklistItem checklistItem;

    //...
}
```

I'm using SpringBoot so I've just got a ChecklistItemRepository interface that extends SpringBoot's CrudRepository:

```
public interface ChecklistItemRepository extends CrudRepository<ChecklistItem, Long> {}
```

In my ChecklistItem service, I've configured the save method to work like so:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ChecklistItemServiceImpl implements ChecklistItemService {

    @Override
    public ChecklistItem saveChecklistItem(ChecklistItem checklistItem) {
        processButtonAction(checklistItem);
        return checklistItemRepository.save(checklistItem);
    }

    private void processButtonAction(ChecklistItem checklistItem,String username) {
        ButtonAction button = checklistItem.getButton();

        if(button != null) {
            button.setChecklistItem(checklistItem);

            if(checklistItem.getId() != null){
                button.setChecklistItemId(checklistItem.getId());
            }
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

So whenever the ChecklistItem gets saved (via POST or PUT), it's updating that ButtonAction (when the user has selected to include one) with a reference to the ChecklistItem, and its ID (if not null) before the save is invoked.

Here's my problem... **When a user *PUTs* a ChecklistItem with a NEW ButtonAction (User initially POSTed a ChecklistItem without a ButtonAction), I get the following error**:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.me.chklapp.checklistitem.action.ButtonAction.checklistItem];
nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.me.chklapp.checklistitem.action.ButtonAction.checklistItem]
```

Every 'answer' I've found online is saying that the relationship needs to be set, but I'm already doing that in my service. I've verified that it's doing just so by debugging and checking that each object has a non-null reference to the other. Also, I couldn't find anyone else having the same problem I'm having, where in some cases, it saves, and in others it breaks; it was all-or-nothing in those cases.

The only fishy thing I was able to see when I turned on more detailed hibernate logging was that right before the error was thrown, it does a select on the buttonaction table where the cheklistitem id matches. I'm guessing Hibernate does this to determine whether it needs to do an insert or an update on the buttonaction table. But maybe it's then using that empty row instead of the ButtonAction object that's on my ChecklistItem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you need these annotations: `@GenericGenerator` `@GeneratedValue` at the `checklistItemId` attribute ... when your button ID is always the CheckedItem ID ... I believe if you remove those annotations everything will work ok ...

Comment: @CarlitosWay I need those to tell Hibernate that the ID is generated from another source, in this case, the OneToOne reference to the ChecklistItem. So I can't remove it entirely, but I've been doing some research and it seems I can accomplish the same thing in a simpler way by using the MapsId annotation. Will be playing around with that, and hopefully that fixes the problem. We'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I'm still not sure why my original problem presented or why this solution works, so if anyone can shed some light on those things, PLEASE comment; I wish to understand better.

Kudos to @CarlitosWay and @Matthew for working with me to try and find a solution. CarlitosWay was on to something when he commented that GeneratedValue and GenericGenerator weren't needed. I couldn't just remove them; *I needed some way to tell Hibernate where to get ButtonAction's ID from*, but it got me started down the track to find alternative configurations. I discovered one that looked promising: **MapsId**. I looked at some examples and fanangled around with things to see what would work. If nothing else, this seemed to confirm that I've got somewhat of a unique setup, as my solution does not resemble the usual examples of what MapsId is used for.

I'm posting my resulting code below, but again, I'm still not entirely sure how Hibernate's working with all of this, so I may have some superfluous annotations here. Please let me know how I can clean this up if possible.

**ButtonAction Class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACTION_BUTTON", schema = "CHKL_APP")
public class ButtonAction implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "checklist_item_id", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private Long checklistItemId;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @JsonIgnore
    private ChecklistItem checklistItem;

    //...
}
```

Basically I exchanged the GenericGenerator and GeneratedValue annotations on the checklistItemId for the MapsId annotation on the checklistItem. In most other examples I'd seen, the MapsId annotation was on the other class (which would be ChecklistItem in this case), but I'm thinking since ButtonAction is the owner of the association and where the ID is coming from, it needs to be on the native object. ChecklistItem, ChecklistItemRepository, and ChecklistItemServiceImpl are all unchanged from my original code in my question.

**Theoretically, my original code is the Hibernate way to do this JPA equivalent. But since they behave differently, I must be misunderstanding something so if you know the reason, please respond!**

Comment: I've never used that annotation, but according to the documentation it belongs to the JPA 2.0 spec. You setup is not so rare... you can check this [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_and_ManyToOne_Relationships)... It give an example using `CheckListItem` as primary Key in the `ActionButton` Entity (JPA2.0)... I guess that using that annotation in simple attribute PK has the same effect as the solution suggested by the link...

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a new ButtonAction whenever an owner ChecklistItem is first created. Then update the ButtonAction as needed.

I'm not exactly sure, but I think there is some Hibernate issue when trying to derive IDs at a later time.

Creating both ButtonAction and ChecklistItem at the same time should work.

Comment: I'm thinking along the same lines for Hibernate's confusion, but enforcing one when it's optional isn't an option. There are not null constraints on ButtonAction that will complain if you try to create a non-nonsensical ButtonAction in the cases where the user has elected not to have one. If I were to remove those not null constraints, well then I'd always have a dummy ButtonAction coming back on ChecklistItems that didn't want a ButtonAction, which would make for some buggy UI displays, and complex logic in the UI if I chose to work around that.

Comment: I you find out more about that issue (if it is one) about deriving an ID at a later time, please do post about it. I think I have run into this before.

Comment: I'm about to post an answer. I'm still not entirely sure why my original setup didn't work, but running with @CarlitosWay's suggestion that GenericGenerator and GeneratedValue weren't needed directed me to search for an alternative annotation setup that seems to have fixed the problem. Look for details in my answer